# Panda read_csv Unable to detect exact format from dateobject

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a excel file and following data, where the date like 01/01/2020 is a date object.

```
| Customer ID | Customer Name | Region Name | Department Name | 01/01/2020 |    01/02/2020 |
|   C1        |     Cname     |  USA        |    Department ! |    1       |        1      |
|   C1        |     Cname     |  USA        |    Department ! |    1       |        1      |
|   C1        |     Cname     |  USA        |    Department ! |    1       |        1      |
```

and when I am trying to read as follow

```
df = pd.read_excel(file, encoding="ISO-8859-1")
df.columns
```

But getting following format

```
2020-01-01 00:00:00
2020-02-01 00:00:00
2020-03-01 00:00:00
2020-04-01 00:00:00
```

which is not same what exatly in my file. I just wanted to get actual format i.e 01/01/2020, 01/02/2020 by panda itself. I can set this format manually but there may be different files with different format, so I can not pre define any fornat. Please suggest what is the appropriate way to achieve this. Any suggestions would be appriciated.

Download reference file from: https://mega.nz/file/wWgnjaKR#HNa8xD55DXx5le83gVPrmsmwQwqECtzYeitvnsOYaAo

Thanks

Comment: When I sent the columns to a list after reading in the headers, this is my output `'Customer ID', 'Customer Name', 'Region Name', 'Department Name',
       '01/01/2020', '01/02/2020'],
      dtype='object'`

Comment: Hi @David Erickson, Thanks for you response. Can you please explain a bit more. Hoe to achoeve this? When I am trying list(df.columns.values) it returns


['Customer ID',
 'Customer Name',
 'Region Name',
 'Department Name',
 datetime.datetime(2020, 1, 1, 0, 0),
 datetime.datetime(2020, 2, 1, 0, 0),
 datetime.datetime(2020, 3, 1, 0, 0),
 datetime.datetime(2020, 4, 1, 0, 0)]

Comment: Is the header in your file in the first row? From your data I cannot reproduce the described behavior as @DavidErickson

Comment: @DavidErickson, Yes, first row in file is header. and columns like 01/01/2020, 01/02/2020 format is date.
.

Comment: @DavidErickson, any idea what could be causing that? When a header in excel file is of type date then it happens. But if the date is simple string it works good.

Comment: @DRJerry can you share one of your example excel files in question?

Comment: @DavidErickson , thanks for the reply. I have Edited my questions and you can download the sample file from https://mega.nz/file/wWgnjaKR#HNa8xD55DXx5le83gVPrmsmwQwqECtzYeitvnsOYaAo

Comment: @DavidErickson, are you able to download that file and re-produce the case?

Comment: @DRJerry do you want to try out what I have suggested in my answer?

Answer (score 0):

You can pass `, header=None` when you `read_excel`. From there use `df.iloc[0,4:]` to select the first row and columns 4 until the end, so that you can manipulate the format for the dates. with `pd.to_datetime` and then `dt.strftime`. Optionally, you can pass `, infer_datetime_format=True` to `pd.to_datetime`. The final line of code promotes the first row to header. I hope this helps.

Input:

```
    0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   10  11  12  13  14  15
0   Customer ID Customer Name   Region Name Department Name 2020-01-01 00:00:00 2020-02-01 00:00:00 2020-03-01 00:00:00 2020-04-01 00:00:00 2020-05-01 00:00:00 2020-06-01 00:00:00 2020-07-01 00:00:00 2020-08-01 00:00:00 2020-09-01 00:00:00 2020-10-01 00:00:00 2020-11-01 00:00:00 2020-12-01 00:00:00
1   C1  Cname   USA Department !    1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1
2   C1  Cname   USA Department !    1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1
3   C1  Cname   USA Department !    1   1   222 1   1   1   1   1   222 1   1   1
4   C1  Cname   USA Department !    1   1   222 1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1
5   C1  Cname   USA Department !    1   1   333 1   1   1   1   1   3222    1   1   1
```

Code:

```
df = pd.read_excel('date-object.xlsx', header=None)
df.iloc[0,4:] = pd.to_datetime(df.iloc[0,4:], infer_datetime_format=True).dt.strftime('%d/%m/%Y')
df = df.rename(columns=df.iloc[0]).drop(df.index[0])
df
```

Output:

```
    Customer ID Customer Name   Region Name Department Name 01/01/2020  01/02/2020  01/03/2020  01/04/2020  01/05/2020  01/06/2020  01/07/2020  01/08/2020  01/09/2020  01/10/2020  01/11/2020  01/12/2020
1   C1  Cname   USA Department !    1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1
2   C1  Cname   USA Department !    1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1
3   C1  Cname   USA Department !    1   1   222 1   1   1   1   1   222 1   1   1
4   C1  Cname   USA Department !    1   1   222 1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1
5   C1  Cname   USA Department !    1   1   333 1   1   1   1   1   3222    1   1   1
```